# HTML Table Cell Width with Photo - Cross Browser

Tags: html, image, html-table, width

I have the following HTML Code:
What I am trying to do is to show an image and under the image to show a text in a Table Cell.
example:

```
<table bgcolor="yellow" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td  width="100%">
                        <img width="100%" src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/cat/cat-01.jpg" border="0"  style="vertical-align: top;"/> <br/>
                        <div  style="background-color: #023F7D">
                            <p>test</p>
                        </div>

                    </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The code above leaves a yellow vertical stripe at the right of the image. Image does not cover the whole TD.

If I put width="100%" in the img Tag the problem is that a yellow stripe appears under the photo. This only happens in IE (in Safari it works fine). 
I want to show the div under the photo without any space.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: add `display:block` to you `img` styles and remove the top margin from your p tag - http://jsfiddle.net/cafT5/

Comment: <br/> was also not required..
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `<p>` tag by default has some margins. So we have to overwrite it by adding margin: 0 to `<p>` tag so that it clears margin for that.